# Invocar a otra función con javascript (jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Quiero llamar a una función de esta forma, alguien sabe como puedo hacerlo?

Función principal: Cuando alguien hace click en .btn-regresar, invoca a la función genérica ConfirmarAccion, pasando como parámetro el nombre de la nueva función a ejecutar.

```
_BODY.on('click', '.btn-regresar', function ()
    {
        ConfirmarAccion('HolaMundo')
    })

function HolaMundo()
    {
        console.log('Soy un mensaje')
    }
```

Función Generica:

> ```
> function ConfirmarAccion(Func)
> {
>     $.confirm({
>         icon: 'fa fa-question',
>         title: 'Confirmación',
>         content: 'Desea finalizar lote?',
>         type: 'green',
>         typeAnimated: true,
>         theme: 'modern',
>         buttons:
>             {
>                 tryAgain:
>                     {
>                         text: 'CONFIRMAR',
>                         btnClass: 'btn-green',
>                         keys: ['enter'],
>                         action: function()
>                         {
>                             self[Func]()
>                         }
>                     },
>                 CANCELAR: function () { }
>             }
>     })
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

En javascript las funciones son [objetos de primera clase](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Glossary/First-class_Function), puedes pasarlas directamente como argumentos a otras funciones.

```
_BODY.on('click', '.btn-regresar', function ()
    {
        ConfirmarAccion(HolaMundo)
    })

function HolaMundo()
    {
        console.log('Soy un mensaje')
    }
```

Dentro de tu función genérica puedes llamar la función con el nombre del argumento que pasas, en este caso `Func()`

Comment: Lo que sucede es que la función HolaMundo se debe ejecutar hasta que la persona presione el botón CONFIRMAR

Comment: y en este momento se ejecuta cuando? Segun la doc de jquery-confirm basta con darle una accion al boton 
`action: function() { Func() }`

Comment: En este [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xg7n2sku/1/) funciona bien. No es eso lo que necesitas?